# vimdiff: force line-by-line comparison (ignore supposedly missing/additional lines)

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

**How do I force vimdiff to always compare two files line-by-line without identifying added or deleted lines?**

The problem is that if the diff between two files is large, but by chance two lines in the file match up, vimdiff thinks these lines are the same and just treats the rest as added or deleted lines, and the resulting diff is totally unusable. In my case, line i in file1 always corresponds to line i in file2, so vimdiff has no business finding added or deleted lines.

Following is a small example with two files containing the values of two variables three times each. Vimdiff erroneously matches up file1/line1 with file2/line3 and thinks some lines around it have been added or deleted. The diff (minus colors) then looks like this:

```
              |  1 foo 8.1047  < del/new
              |  2 bar 6.2343  < del/new
1 foo 0.0000  |  3 foo 0.0000  < match
2 bar 5.3124  |  4 bar 1.4452  < wrong
3 foo 4.5621  |                < new/del
4 bar 6.3914  |                < new/del
5 foo 1.0000  |  5 foo 1.0000  < match
6 bar 6.3212  |  6 bar 7.2321  < wrong
```

What I want, however, is the following, with all lines marked as wrong except for the matching lines 5:

```
1 foo 0.0000  |  1 foo 8.1047 < wrong
2 bar 5.3124  |  2 bar 6.2343 < wrong
3 foo 4.5621  |  3 foo 0.0000 < wrong
4 bar 6.3914  |  4 bar 1.4452 < wrong
5 foo 1.0000  |  5 foo 1.0000 < match
6 bar 6.3212  |  6 bar 7.2321 < wrong
```

Comment: you may want to use "sdiff file1 file2" instead of vimdiff ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac: No not really, the files I'm comparing in these cases are much longer and I want to scroll through them, so vimdiff is just fine. I wasn't aware of `sdiff`, though, definitely handy to compare short files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [diffchar.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932) plugin? It compares line-by-line in non-diff mode. Please open 2 files on 2 windows and then just press F7. By default, it tries to find the differences by characters in a line, but you can change the difference units, words or something.

Comment: Wow, this plugin is amazing! Apart from the fact that running it in non-diff mode does indeed exactly what I was looking for (which is why I except your's as the answer), it greatly improves vimdiff overall by reducing the diff highlight to the actual differences! It has always annoyed me that if there are two diffs on one line, the whole area between these diffs is highlighted, not just the actual differences, which e.g. greatly complicates scanning the diff of two codes with a renamed variable or something along that line, and this plugin totally resolves that problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RickHowe, yours is a must-have plugin!

Comment: Since version 8.0 of the plugin, this solution does not work anymore. @rick-howe, is there a workaround?

Comment: diffchar.vim now works only on diff mode since 8.0. Please upload https://github.com/rickhowe/sample/blob/master/mylinediff.vim to set diffexpr option and check the line-by-line contents. Do not forget to do 'diffthis' on both windows.

Answer (score 12):

As I was copying this example to try it, I noticed that `vimdiff` will do what you want if you have the line number associated with each line.

Therefore, you can use `cat` to add the line number and then diff:

```
  cat -n file1 > file1_with_line_no
  cat -n file2 > file2_with_line_no

  vimdiff file1_with_line_no file2_with_line_no
```

The output is then as you want (shown with `diff` for easy copying to here):

```
 diff file1_with_line_no file2_with_line_no --side-by-side
 1  foo 0.0000                                            |      1  foo 8.1047
 2  bar 5.3124                                            |      2  bar 6.2343
 3  foo 4.5621                                            |      3  foo 0.0000
 4  bar 6.3914                                            |      4  bar 1.4452
 5  foo 1.0000                                                   5  foo 1.0000
 6  bar 6.3212                                            |      6  bar 7.2321
```

In bash you can add this to your `.bashrc` so you can use `linediff` from the command line to just normally call a diff between two files with the above:

```
linediff() { 
     if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then return; fi
     f1=$(basename "$1")
     f2=$(basename "$2")
     cat -n "$1" > "/tmp/$f1"
     cat -n "$2" > "/tmp/$f2"
     vimdiff "/tmp/$f1" "/tmp/$f2"
     rm "/tmp/$f1" "/tmp/$f2"
 }
```

and now `linediff file1 file2` will do the above and clean up after.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's actually a decent enough workaround for my specific case (in which I don't need to edit the files), if there really is no such feature in vimdiff. I'm still hoping for the latter, though, since this workaround breaks as soon as I wanted to edit the diffed files.

Comment: OK so I've gone through `man diff`, but there doesn't seem to be such an option... The only thing I've at least given a shot is `-d` (`--minimal` seems to do the same), which apparently uses some more sophisticated algorithm to minimize the diff (though no further details whatsoever are given on this), but at least for my example in the question it didn't change anything.

Comment: This is so great I wrapped it in a bash function. Hope you don't mind me adding it to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Vim relies on the external `diff` command to analyze the two files, so you can influence the result via a different tool that uses a different algorithm. You can configure that via the `'diffexpr'` option; the tool's output has to be in "ed" style. Cp. `:help diff-diffexpr`.

Note that this only affects the lines added / changed / deleted; for displaying the character differences in a changed line itself, Vim does that on its own.

Unfortunately, I don't know any alternative diff tool that could provide such output, but maybe others can fill in that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to diffexpr. I've already been pretty sure that vimdiff just uses diff under the hood, now I know where to look for. Do you know `diff` well enough to be pretty sure that this feature doesn't exist (or are you just now by chance aware of it)? (I guess I should just dive headfirst into `man diff`...)